# remove the element attached to the image border

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, detection

I'm using OpenCV to detect Pneumonia in chest-x-ray using Image Processing, so I need to remove the attached area to the image border to get the lung only, can anyone help me code this in python?

This image explains what I want [this image after applying this methods: resized, Histogram Equalization, otsu Thresholded and inverse binary Thresholded,  morphological processes(opening then closing)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5R0Zs.jpg)

This is the Original Image [Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpAS1.jpg)

Comment: Sorry, this is not how stackoverflow works. Please repeat [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please explain in more detail identifying what are you want. Do you want the black area to made transparent? Or do you want it trimmed to the smallest bounding box around the white area. Or do you want each white area separated. We do not know how what you mean by "remove" ! Please post your code and your original image.

Comment: I want to get lung area with white only and convert other white areas to background (black area)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I would approach the problem in Python/OpenCV. Add a white border all around, flood fill it with black to replace the white, then remove the extra border.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image
img = cv2.imread('lungs.jpg')
h, w = img.shape[:2]

# convert to gray
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# add 1 pixel white border all around
pad = cv2.copyMakeBorder(gray, 1,1,1,1, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value=255)
h, w = pad.shape

# create zeros mask 2 pixels larger in each dimension
mask = np.zeros([h + 2, w + 2], np.uint8)

# floodfill outer white border with black
img_floodfill = cv2.floodFill(pad, mask, (0,0), 0, (5), (0), flags=8)[1]

# remove border
img_floodfill = img_floodfill[1:h-1, 1:w-1]    

# save cropped image
cv2.imwrite('lungs_floodfilled.png',img_floodfill)

# show the images
cv2.imshow("img_floodfill", img_floodfill)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can try using a morphological reconstruction with a border as a marker. This is an analogue of the function imclearborder from Matlab or Octave.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread('5R0Zs.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 40, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
kernel = np.ones((7,7),np.uint8)
kernel2 = np.ones((3,3),np.uint8)
marker = thresh.copy()
marker[1:-1,1:-1]=0
while True:
    tmp=marker.copy()
    marker=cv2.dilate(marker, kernel2)
    marker=cv2.min(thresh, marker)
    difference = cv2.subtract(marker, tmp)
    if cv2.countNonZero(difference) == 0:
        break

mask=cv2.bitwise_not(marker)
mask_color = cv2.cvtColor(mask, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
out=cv2.bitwise_and(img, mask_color)
cv2.imwrite('out.png', out)
cv2.imshow('result', out )
cv2.waitKey(0) # waits until a key is pressed
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your output that what i want, but in my code i have an error. I will show you my full code if you want, and this is the error.
The error in this statement:     out=cv2.bitwise_and(img, mask_color)
TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'src1'

Comment: Try replacing the first argument img  with the gray  or thresh. out = cv2.bitwise_and (gray, mask_color) or  out = cv2.bitwise_and (thresh, mask_color). This is due to the number of channels in the image.

Comment: Also make sure the image img was read from disk.